# Ubuntu 22.04 File sharing (write permissions issue) with Windows 10/11

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I have been struggling with getting a shared Samba share in Linux to be writable from Windows 10/11. I have found several questions on this but can't find a solution. I can see and list the samba share without any issues, simply can't create or write files. Tested on 2 different Windows machines.

I did have this setup working a few years ago and if memory serves I had to install additional features in windows and a couple of tweaks in the smb.conf but not sure what those were. I have tried mounting the HDD using both `ntfs-3g` and `cifs`, using the `uid` and `gid` for a user I created for samba shares *netuser*, included `force user = netuser`, setting `fmask=000`, `dmask=000`, and `rw`, all with no luck.

One thing I noticed when looking at the permissions from windows it shows the owner as *netuser*, Everyone has only Special Permissions and looking at the Advanced Permissions shows Access with Full control.

My current fstab

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1 ntfs-3g x-gvfs-show,dmask=000,fmask=000,rw,uid=1001,gid=1001 0 0
```

Samba Config

```
[PublicFiles]
path = /mnt/sda1/Public
guest ok = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

I realize this setup is insecure (testing only), once I find the problem I can tighten things back down. I have not added any Windows Features, are there any I need to check to enable write permissions?

I know there has been a lot of changes, especially in recent years, is Samba still the way to set this up? I have seen NFS thrown around quite a bit but I am not familiar with it. Figured Samba would be easiest way to get this setup done since it's simply for internal file sharing/organization. I would be open to other ways to get this working if need be.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I use:

**(1)** In Linux:   \\192.168.x.y\folder  where this is the IP of the Windows Machine

**(2)** In Windows:  **Implement Samba on Linux.**

Follow this tutorial

[Samba Tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba)

1. Installing Samba

In the Linux machine, install Samba .

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install samba
```

Use  whereis samba to verify the install.

2. Setting up Samba .

Make a directory to share:  mkdir /home//sambashare .

Edit the smb.conf file:  sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf .

Add the following lines at the bottom of the file:

```
[sambashare}
comment = Samba on Ubuntu
path = /home/<username>/sambashare
read only = no
browsable = yes
```

Ctrl-O to save and Ctrl-X to exit the editor .

Restart the samba service:   sudo service smd restart .

Update the firewall rules if necessary:  sudo ufw allow samba  .

Setting up User Accounts and Connecting to Share

sudo smbpasswd -a    and password

(username must belong to a system account or it will not work)

In Linux:

smb://ip_address_of_Linux/sambashare

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the share to show up and everything, I can see the files from windows, only problem is I can't seem to be able to write from windows.

Comment: Are your account credentials correct according to the tutorial. No issue here transferring files (so writing) between Windows and Ubuntu.